# Does an items DPS value include all stats?

Tags: pixel-privateers

I'm struggling to understand which weapons are the 'best' fit for my privateers. So far I can gather from looking at the game that heavier weapons hit harder, but less frequently, and lighter damage weapons hit faster.

I've tried equipping my team with weapons which focus on the pure DPS number, and using the character panel to keep an eye on damage. However this lead to me using melee and two handed weapons, and made my team's ability to deal with multiple enemies much tougher.

So how is the items show DPS number calculated? Does it take into account the characters stats? Does it include any stat bonuses on the item? How can I better use this to understand which items to equip my team with?

Here is a good example of a choice, as the +20 to speed would increase melee rate, increasing DPS.

[image]

Comment: I also got confirmation from a developer on the Steam Forums. http://steamcommunity.com/app/342640/discussions/0/1368380934258239849/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DPS shows just the 'basic' DPS with none of your stats included. It will count mix-max damage on a weapon, basic attacks per second, clip size and reload times into the DPS tooltip, also it will count any flat elemental damage bonus, but it seems to show bigger numbers for elemental DPS than it supposed to. It will never show the boost from speed or strength there, not even mentioning +% damage things there, as it will never appear even in character screen stats, but will work in-combat. I think I'll just make a calculator in exel for myself for hard choices between stat-heavy legendaries.